# How does the CRM Organization Service Proxy know my credentials when I pass in a default ClientCredentials Instance?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am connecting to the CRM Organization Service Proxy by passing in a default instance of ClientCredentials. This is allowing me to connect to my ON-Premise CRM solution. How is it allowing me to do this if I don't pass in a Username or Password?

Granted, my Domain's username and password is the same  as the On-Premise's one but what property on the ClientCredentials is allowing me to login by just passing a default instance of ClientCredentials?

Answer (score 0):

No property at all. You can pass a `null` value as well.

It simply tells the client to use Integrated Windows Authentication. The application uses the identity of your Windows session to authenticate you. Your identity is negotiated using cryptographic tokens.